NextJS route handler working when visiting directly via browser searchbar, but doesn't work when console logging it
Basically, I am trying to access some JSON placeholder data via my route handler defined in /api/posts/route.js
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const data = await res.json();

  return Response.json({ data: data });
}

I know that this part is OK because when I navigate to

http://localhost:3000/api/posts

a whole JSON object with this data appears on the page.
However, when I am trying to get this data via console logging in my

/posts/page.jsx

file, it just logs an empty object. Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks!
import React from 'react';

export async function getPosts() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/posts');

  const data = await res.json();

  return data.data;
}

const Post = async () => {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;


kindly use states and use effects to render API data on JSX files, The way you've implemented the Post component with async/await directly in the component's function isn't the standard approach, particularly because React components need to handle re-renders properly.

Your code doesn't leverage React's lifecycle effectively. Using async directly in the function body doesn't fit well with React framework. React Components are expected to return JSX synchronously and you are trying to return promise which is asynchronous by using use effect and use state you can avoid async re-rendering + handle sideeffects more effecient
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Post = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/posts');
      const data = await res.json();
      setPosts(data.data);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []); 

  console.log(posts);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;

